# sql server and php on ubuntu 9.004

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, php

first post here but already used stack overflow and was so impressed... :)

hope i'm not off topic here

i run development env on my ubuntu pc php is installed and runing but when calling phpmyadmin i get this error

> Cannot load mcrypt extension. Please check your PHP configuration.

checking on installed packages it is installed 
any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your package manager and view all php packages. You will find an mcrypt package, not installed. Install this package with all dependencies, there are non-PHP libraries that this package depends on. restart apache with 'apachectl restart' after you have done this.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by restarting apache2

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

hopefully someone can use this in the future... :)